# Referencing the last (n) values from a column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

Lets assume that I have a table in Excel that looks like below. The table is updated on a daily basis and contains empty fields for future dates.

How can I reference a range of values in this table, starting from the last entered non-empty cell and going upwards from there to get the values from the last 7 days for instance?

```
Date          Value
2017-01-18    6
2017-01-19    5
2017-01-20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-MIN(6,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))
```

This assumes you have 1 entry per day and that the days are sorted.

[image]

If there is not 1 entry per day and you only want the data that is from 7 days back, so there may only be 5 or 6 entries then use this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=" & INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))-6,A:A,"<="& INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))
```